# Reload UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm trying to reload data in a `UITableViewController` after a location is found. This also means after the `viewDidLoad` method. My class is extending a `UITableViewController` with this interface:

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

in the implementation I try to reload data using

```
[self.view reloadData];
```

`reloadData` doesn't seem to be a method of UITableViewController or the view because I get an error:

```
Messages without a matching method signature will be assumed to return 'id' and accept '...' as arguments
```

Can someone please post some code of how to reload a table view extended like in my case?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

you have to do it on the `UITableView` over `[self.tableView reloadData];`

Comment: wouldn't this only work if the uitableview was an outlet?  the class above is a uitableviewcontroller.

Comment: It works because tableView is a property of UITableViewController. Outlets don't have anything to do with that, they are used to connect interface builder files with code.

Comment: If it worked, you should probably accept this as an answer to the question.